# tuples, packing and unpacking perfomance in Python

Tags: python, tuples

Two classes using tuples, unpacking and packing.
Why the perfomance of these 2 classes so different - 2000 times. Is this line so expensive?
`*self.stack, outitem = self.stack`

```
from time import time


class StackT:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = tuple()

    def push(self, otheritem):
        self.stack = (*self.stack, otheritem)

    def pop(self):
        *self.stack, outitem = self.stack
        return outitem


class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self._items = None
        self._size = 0

    def push(self, item):
        self._items = (item, self._items)

    def pop(self):
        (item, self._items) = self._items
        return item


def timer(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("starting count.")
        now = time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"counted {time() - now} seconds")
        return result
    return wrapper


@timer
def f(cls, times):
    print(f"class {cls.__name__}, {times} times")
    stack = cls()
    for i in range(times):
        stack.push(i)
    for i in range(times):
        stack.pop()
```

```
f(StackT, 100_000)
f(Stack, 100_000)

# starting count.
# class StackT, 100000 times
# counted 63.61870002746582 seconds
# starting count.
# class Stack, 100000 times
# counted 0.02500009536743164 seconds
```

Comment: with a profiler you can investigate the bottleneck of a program, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) a possibility from the standard library

Answer (score 1):

The explanations provided in comments are correct:

1. Your `StackT` needs to build a new, flat tuple at every insert, and that tuple gets longer and longer, so each insertion is on average `O(n)`, and `n` insertions is `O(n^2)`.
2. By contrast, your `Stack` makes nested tuples, so each insertion, while making a new tuple each time, is `O(1)`.

It is worth considering a list-based stack:

```py
class StackL(list):
    def push(self, item):
        self.append(item)

    @property
    def size(self):
        return len(self)
```

On my system, it is 2.4x faster than your nested `Stack`.

Comment: You could also try `push = list.append`, should be faster. The O(1) of their `Stack`might be a reason to do that. You don't get that with your list.

Comment: Hmm, we might be wrong about that O(1). I tried measuring maximum push time for a million pushes. StackL has ~0.3 ms and Stack has a whopping ~75 ms. [Code](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZHNSgQxDMfx2qfIsZXZYRYvsuBprosXH6CU2dQtTj9oM6C-ipe96Lv4Cj6Nk5nZYRUEC4Uk_-TXpHn7SC90jOF0eh_Ibm6_rj5tjh7IeQTnU8wECbPVXRwCYQZTJk2IrjelwAOZ7mknYDwHtKC1C460lgV7q-Y4H3Zr7Qh9gTu4jwF_ScW94qg0YkWloRwnTAVc9ydMslFdBtWP5vayd4XU7r9gkxKGw0QdQVxgY5Q885LJ9eO7pWZjitDocoJUa4JsZjsjDTksKmyAhLAxQwsuLO1Vl3_IA7VnTHaBZFtrHYxHrSvw5lmuzQBzNHOyCY8ot7ppGr5KwTVs8UbNG10We17wNw).

Comment: perhaps on a small memory machine with lots of alloc/gc? In principle, it should be `O(1)` (create a tuple of `(value, ref_to_other_tuple)`).

Comment: It's only ~70 MB. With 100_000 pushes it's only a few MB and max times are ~0.2 ms and ~8 ms. Yes, it should be O(1) but looks like allocs mess that up. My original point was that one might want to do it their way in order to prevent the rare large times when list.append reallocates, but turns out their way might be far worse at that...

Comment: Interesting, it's not random. If I do 87425 pushes, max time is always around 0.8 ms. If I do 87426 pushes, max time is always around 7 ms. Apparently it's always the 87426th push that's much slower.

Comment: With `StackT`, there is a ton of small allocs (and much opportunity for fragmentation as well). `GarbageCollector` is probably trying to consolidate released blocks, and on the kernel where your `code` is running, that happens at the 87426th push. If you first allocate a few tuple of a few items first, you'll perhaps see happen sooner. By contrast, reallocating a list is done in larger contiguous blocks. I haven't looked at Python's implementation, but back in the old days these things would be done by doubling the underlying array each time we need more room.

Comment: It's not StackT but Stack and I only push, so no releases. But GC is a good point. If I do `gc.disable()` at the start, then the ~75 ms turn into ~1 ms, often less, sometimes much less than the max time for StackL. Just had a run with 0.6 ms for StackL and 0.06 ms for Stack.

Comment: Looks like the 87426th push triggers the first garbage collection of generation 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Stacks` have attributes of different type. By that I mean that:

- `StackT.stack` is a tuple of `items`
- `Stack.items` is a tuple of tuple

Your intuition and the comment of @zvone are right. The `push/pop` functions of `StackT` are more expensive because you use the `* operator` that unlist the elements of your `tuple` `StackT.stack` with is costly since it has the same complexity of looping over the tuple.

## Remarks

`StackT` is more flexible and easy to manipulate since every element are in a tuple and accessing an element is equivalent to having its index/order, but is computationally expensive as it is implemented.

- `Stack` is more optimized but has a more complex attribute to manipulate since only having its index is not enough. You need to use some looping mecanisms.
- when having such issues profiling is a good practice as proposed by @cards, there are many options on python. I personally use cProfile + snakeviz(for visualization purposes).